# onkeyup function only calculate first digit only. based on my formula why?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to develop a small vat calculator with dynamic row features but when i try this with onkeyup function it's only calculating first number.

example if i type slowly 10 is calculating for 1 not for 10 why?

```
<table id="myTable">
  <th>Gross amount</th><th>VAT Type</th>
  <tr><td><b>Net Total</b></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>Std Total</b></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>Zero VAT</b></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td><b>Gross Total</b></td><td></td></tr>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" >Try it</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var a = 1;
  var b = 1;
  function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

    cell1.innerHTML = "<input type=number onkeyup = myCalc() />";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<div></div>";

    let input = document.querySelector("input");
    input.setAttribute("id", "id");
    input.id = "gross" + a++;

    let div = document.querySelector("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "id");
    div.id = "vat" + b++;
  }
</script>

<script>
  var c = 1;
  var d = 1;
  function myCalc(){
    var g = document.getElementById("gross"+c).value;
    var v = 6;
    var r = parseInt(g) / parseInt(v); 

    document.getElementById("vat" + d).innerHTML = r.toFixed(2);
    c++;
    d++;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myCalc(){
var g = document.getElementById("gross"+c).value;
var v = 6;
var r = parseInt(g) / parseInt(v); 

document.getElementById("vat"+d).innerHTML=r.toFixed(2);
c++;
d++;
}
```

Note that at the end of this function, you increment `c`. So you type once, and it grabs the element with the id `gross1`, then does some stuff and then increments c to 2. Now the next time you type, it tries to grab the element with the id `gross2`, which is not the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

Putting the event listener on the input, rather than the table cell containing it gets much better results.

Also watch out for concatenating strings with incrementing numbers at the same time.

```html
<html>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
<th>Gross amount</th><th>VAT Type</th>
<tr><td><b>Net Total</b></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Std Total</b></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Zero VAT</b></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Gross Total</b></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" >Try it</button>
<script>
var a = 1;
function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

let newInput = document.createElement('input');
  newInput.type = 'number';
  newInput.id = "input_" + (a);
  newInput.addEventListener('keyup', (event)=>{
    let thisElem = event.currentTarget;
    let input_value = thisElem.value;
    let VAT = 0.7
    let result = input_value * VAT;
    let output_id = 'output_' + thisElem.id.split('_')[1]
    document.getElementById(output_id).innerHTML = result;
  })
  cell1.appendChild(newInput);
  cell2.innerHTML = "<div></div>";
  cell2.id = "output_" + (a);
  a++;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```